# Can selected option tag can carry multiple values using django?

Tags: html, django

I just want to get the ID and at the same time the adddate.

I have this selection in my html

```
<select id="days" name="days" onchange="periods(this)" required>
     <option>-----</option>
     {% for perfume in s %}
     <option value="{{perfume.id}}" value="{{perfume.adddate}}" data-days="{{perfume.adddate}}">{{perfume.product}}  -  {{perfume.adddate}} Days </option>
     {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML you cannot have multiple values on option elements.

As the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-option-value) says:

> The value content attribute provides a value for element. The value of an option element is the value of the value content attribute, if there is one, or, if there is not, the value of the element’s text IDL attribute (which may be the empty string).

If we can set multiple values that would lead to ambiguous behaviour.

You can try to create a string which contains `perfume.id` and `perfume.addate` joined by some special character and use this string as a value. Then you will just split it and will have both `id` and `addate`. However, you will need to carefully pick a special character, that would not be included in any the `id` or `addate` value, because your splitting will not work correctly otherwise.

Comment: can you give me an example sir?

Comment: Actually, I'm not familiar with Python and Django, but setting the value attribute should be pretty trivial like ``value="{{perfume.id + '@' + perfume.adddate}}"``. Then, when the form is submitted, you can try to [split](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) by the custom character - in the example above it is the @.